# Azure db link in Oracle db.ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:

Tags: database, oracle, azure

I've created db link on oracle database to azure db. The problem is that when i do for example:
select *
from schema.db_table@azure_db

i have normal result.
But when i want to take specific column i have error:
'ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SMux Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].  {08S02,NativeErr = -1}[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to open a logical session {08S02,NativeErr = -1}'

I tried to use uppercases, lowercases, "" etc. Nothing works if i want take one specific column.

Does someone had similar problem?